# Entity cache in Redis with TTL dosent work in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I want to cache a `UserInfo` entity in redis for just 3600 seconds and accord to my searches and examples that I saw, I implemented Redis caching in spring like below code and i have an issue with cache and uncache (with define ttl) when I cache a `UserInfo` entity in redis.

The whole code is here:

**UserInfo** entity:

```
@RedisHash(value = "UserInfo", timeToLive = 3600)
public class UserInfo implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2048972398004272098L;

    @Id
    private int id = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100000);

    private Long expiration;

    private String userName;

    private String name;
    private String familyName;
    private String givenName;
    private String language;
    private Set<String> roles;
    private Set<String> permissions;
    private String authorizationToken;
    private String action;
    private String path;
    private String remoteAddr;

    //getter & setter
}
```

This is my RedisConfiguration:

```
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP, keyspaceConfiguration = RedisKeyspaceConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
public class RedisConnectionConfig
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RedisConnectionConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
    private String redisPass;


    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory()
    {
        logger.info("================================================================");
        logger.info("Redis config : {} : {} ", host, port);
        logger.info("================================================================");
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);         
            redisConfig.setPassword(redisPass);
                    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisConfig);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> template() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds(3600));
        return RedisCacheManager
                .builder(RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(redisConnectionFactory))
                .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();
    }    
}
```

And this is RedisKeyspaceConfiguration class that I define in

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP, keyspaceConfiguration = RedisKeyspaceConfiguration.class)
```

annotation on redis config class :

```
public class RedisKeyspaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {
@Override
public boolean hasSettingsFor(Class<?> type) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public KeyspaceConfiguration.KeyspaceSettings getKeyspaceSettings(Class<?> type) {

    KeyspaceSettings keyspaceSettings = new KeyspaceSettings(UserInfo.class, "UserInfo");
    keyspaceSettings.setTimeToLive(3600L);

    return keyspaceSettings;
}}
```

And RedisRepository :

```
    public interface UserAuthInfoRepository extends CrudRepository<UserInfo, Integer>
{
    UserInfo findById(int id);
    UserInfo findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

And finally this is when I cache it into redis:

```
  public UserInfo cacheUserAuthDataToRedis(UserInfo userInfo) throws AdminUserAuthorizationException
{
    UserInfo result = null;
    result = userAuthInfoRepository.save(userInfo);
    return result;    
}
```

And also application.properties file:

```
#Redis Config
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.password=
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=360000
```

Now when I call `cacheUserAuthDataToRedis` method as you can see in screenshot 1, data stored in redis and they has a TTL time into TTL box and they will be delete from redis after ttl time runs out and everything is ok :

[image]

But as you can see in picture2 there is a another row name `UserInfo` and the item that there is here they do not disappear because the TTL of them is -1 and they are will stored forever:

[image]

**Please**

1. Tell me if you know a better solution for implement this purpose
2. Help me resolve the issue in screenshot #2

I appreciate your help